# Moodle force privacy policy at first login

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

I have to include on our `Moodle 2.9.5` a function for the new student, who have to go to a page at `first login` and `confirm` the universities `privacy policy`.

In Moodle there is only `force password` change at first login, but not force a page.

Does anyone has an example or a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Moodle has a setting for that exact purpose.

Go to "Administration > Site administration > Security > Site policies". See setting "[sitepolicy](http://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Site_policies#Site_policy_URL)":

> - If you have a site policy that all users must see and agree to before using this site, then specify the URL to it here, otherwise
>     leave this field blank. The URL can point to any type of file anywhere
>     online that can be accessed without a log in to your Moodle.
> - It is recommended that the site policy is on the same domain as Moodle to avoid the problem of Internet Explorer users seeing a blank
>     screen when the site policy is on a different domain.
> - The site policy will be displayed in a frame. You can view it via the URL yourmoodlesite.org/user/policy.php.